# How to test dates with jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm writing a test to check if the selected date is greater than the current date.
This is the component I'm trying to test:

```
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState<Moment>();

<TimeComponent>
  <SetTimeButton 
    data-testid="scheduleTime"
    onClick={() =>
      scheduleTimeHandler(
        selectedDate,
        timeSelect,
        setSelectedDate,
        setTimeDialog,
        setDisableConfirm
      )
    }
  />
  <DisplayDate data-testid="selectedDate">{selectedDate}</DisplayDate>
</TimeComponent>
```

and this is the test that I wrote:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import TimeComponent from './TimeComponent';

test('set schedule time', () => {
  render(
    //@ts-ignore
    <TimeComponent />
  );

  const mockDateObject = new Date();
  const scheduleTimeBtn = screen.queryByTestId('scheduleTime');
  const selectedDate = screen.queryByTestId('selectedDate');

  fireEvent.click(scheduleTimeBtn);

  expect(selectedDate).toBeGreaterThan(+mockDateObject);
});
```

and I'm getting this kind of error regarding the `selectedDate` in `expect`

> expect(received).toBeGreaterThan(expected)

> Matcher error: received value must be a number or bigint

> Received has value: null
> I understand this is because selectedDate is an HTML element instead of being date, but I'm not sure how can I make it a date. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Convert to something comparable, in this case, seconds from epoch.  Date.getTime()

Comment: Your component would either accept the `Date` as prop, or "create" it internally, since in your test you're not passing the `Date` I assume it's the second. You can use jest's [fakeTimers](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestusefaketimersfaketimersconfig) to ensure consistency and either expect a callback to have been called with specific date or a date to be rendered by the component in specific format